# Windows 10 multiple desktop dual monitors swapping

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, desktop

I am using Windows 10 and I have dual monitors. When I create multiple desktops and when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>WIN</kbd> + RIGHT or LEFT <kbd>ALT</kbd> both monitor desktops move together so does anybody know how can I move separately?

As we know Dual monitor with MAC OS you can change the desktops separately.

Comment: Ctrl-Win-Right/Left move the active window between monitors. When you say "desktop", do you mean "monitor"? Because virtual desktops are something else.

Comment: I have two monitors and when I move the desktops (Ctrl-Win-Right/Left) both monitors are moves. I am new on WIN and when I use Mac you can move the desktops separately on your both monitors

Comment: Desktops don't move. I think there is still a terminology gap here. Please use Windows terms for me to understand the problem.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4s0p3i/how_to_create_independent_virtual_desktop_on_dual/

Comment: It still makes no sense.  Monitors don't move.  Application Windows on one desktop move to another desktop and each window is separate.  **Unless you mean that you want two independent desktop groups, one for each monitor.**